# How to select by a timestamp in MariaDB database without getting an Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception?

Tags: sql, mariadb, timestamp

I am trying to select the most recently created code from a login code database where that code was created in the last 60 seconds. I am trying to do this with only a MariaDB query, but am getting this error code when I try to run it:

> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')
> ORDER BY created_at
> DESC LIMIT 1' at line 4

The query:

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT * 
        FROM login_codes 
        WHERE u_id = ? 
        AND created_at >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 60 SECOND) 
        ORDER BY created_at DESC 
        LIMIT 1");
```

I have also tried other functions like SUBTIME, but nothing seems to work. The query does work if I remove the entire 'AND created_at' line, but obviously I lose the purpose of the query.

Comment: You are sure that `TIMESTAMP_SUB` is a valid function in mariadb

Comment: There is no `TIMESTAMP_SUB`  function  in MariaDB. See [Date & Time Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date-time-functions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such timestamp function

you can do instead

```
SELECT * 
    FROM login_codes 
    WHERE u_id = ? 
    AND created_at >= TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, -60, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) 
    ORDER BY created_at DESC 
    LIMIT 1;
```

Or

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM login_codes 
    WHERE u_id = ? 
    AND created_at >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND  
    ORDER BY created_at DESC 
    LIMIT 1;
```